# iPhone video camera streaming

Tags: iphone, video

Can anyone confirm how an app like this is done?

[PocketCam](http://www.senstic.com/iphone/pocketcam/pocketcam.aspx)

Is the way to capture the camera's video stream using AVFoundation?

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009544

To be clear, I dont want to capture the video and save it, I want to stream it over a wireless network as an IP camera.

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't confirm how PocketCam works, however, as of iOS4, AVFoundation *is* the correct way to do this. You will receive a callback with the frame you need. At that point you would push the frame as an image to some server computer listening on the network waiting for frames. Keep in mind that you could be receiving a lot of frames and you may not have enough bandwidth to push all of them depending on the quality/size/resolution of the frames. Here is a [technical note from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1702.html) that discusses how to implement frame captures with AVFoundation.

Comment: Thanks Matt - I just picked up your book on Core Animation ;-)

Comment: no problem. any chance you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541258/objective-c-core-animation-how-to-add-an-animated-layer-at-a-specific-index?

Comment: Hi @MattLong hoping for your advice on a thorny question: is using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool the only way to merge images and text into a video? The goal is to export a MP4 video with images and text superimposed on a user video. Exporting seems slow with AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool so trying to find alternatives. Thanks!